# Why is my WPF Listview Visibility not being updated?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is some of the code inside the project:
Viewmodel:

```
private bool _state;
        public bool State
        {
            get { return _state; }
            set
            {
                _state = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(State));
            }
        }
...

public SettingsViewModel() {
            SwitchCommand = new DelegateCommand(execute: DetermineState, canExecute => true);
            //SwitchCommand = new DelegateCommand(DetermineState);
        }

        private void DetermineState(object? parameter)
        {
            switch (parameter?.ToString())
            {
                case "foo":
                     _state = true;
                   break;
            }
         }
```

Listview XAML:

```
 <ListView
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                Visibility="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}"
                x:Name="ExampleList">
```

BoolToVisibility Converter

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool && (bool)value) return Visibility.Visible;
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible) return true;
            return false;
        }
```

The command is being called with a button with the command parameter "foo" this gets called and works fine with state being updated to true. However, when I put breakpoints inside my BoolToVisbilityConverter class it never gets called. The Datacontext and viewmodel are instantiated and set properly in the code-behind.

```
private SettingsViewModel _viewModel;
public Settings()
        {
            _viewModel = new SettingsViewModel();
            DataContext = _viewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

When the button is pressed nothing happens, state gets turned to true but the listview itself stays in the collapsed state.

I've tried removing UpdateSourceTrigger, using Mode=TwoWay, changing the types to Visibility types, not using a converter and instead setting the .Visibility property in the command. What resulted is the same, listview visibility never gets updated.

Comment: You must use the property set() in order to trigger the PropertyChanged event. If you don't call the set() then the code inside the setter is never executed and all you are doing is a simple assignment to a private field. Simply replace `_state = true` with `State = true`. Also .NET comes with a [`BoolToVisibilityConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) that you can directly use. No need to implement it again on your own.

Comment: @BionicCode. That was it, I've spent way too much time to trying to figure out why it wasn't changing. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TMcKeown because it is better code for free. When you refactor the property name, you can not forget to change the string. You wouldn't use a string literal in modern code when you could use nameof.

Comment: no... you can omit the name parameter...

Comment: I can see your point if calling the PropertyChanged from some other location.. but in the setter, calling it empty would be better... i will update my answer.  i understand your point tho..

Comment: @Clemens, your point is sticking.. i will use nameof when not in setter... thanks!

Comment: @TMcKeown How you have to call the OnPropertyChanged method depends on the method signature. It's not correct to say *"you can omit the name parameter"*, you can't make this a general principle.

Comment: if the goal is to not use string based parameters then I would use the CallerMember example like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

This code here will not result in PropertyChangedEvent being triggered, I have changed it so that the setter is called.

```
private void DetermineState(object? parameter)
{
    switch (parameter?.ToString())
    {
        case "foo":
            State = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

And your setter should simply be:

```
public bool State
{
    get { return _state; }
    set
    {
        if (_state != value)
        {
            _state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Always challenge the setter to determine if there is truly a change in value. This can have huge performance implications on larger applications if you blindly trigger the `OnPropertyChanged()`

And by using the [CallerMemberName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-7.0) attribute you can omit the property name when calling from a setter.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
...

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```